# How to view full images on hover in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, images, google-chrome-extensions

Given a URL to an image, how can I easily insert images into cells into Google Sheets and then have the full images viewable on hover?

I'll be doing this on the fly with many images throughout the day, so the fewer clicks, the better.

I have tried Chrome extensions like ImageHover and Imagus, but neither seem to work with either inline or linked images within cells.

Comment: Clearly **still** lacking a way to zoom in-cell images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you can insert URL into a cell in this or similar format **`https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV4QM.png`** 
   and then **hover over hovered link**

  [image: 4]

---

- or you can insert an image into a cell and make it active: 
  **`=HYPERLINK("https://i.imgur.com/dcAoUzp.jpg",IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/dcAoUzp.jpg",4,90,160))`**

  and then hover over a hovered link (notice the mouse cursor)

  [image: 5]

---

**https://github.com/extesy/hoverzoom/ 

[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom%20/pccckmaobkjjboncdfnnofkonhgpceea)**

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Ah, you need to open a new window for it to work.  Might be worth adding this note to your answer.  Thank you!  +1

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It seems you can now only hover to see Google Drive images, and not external images, and it also just shows a small fixed-size image.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to insert links and get the image to pop up, however, when I have multiple links to images in one spreadsheet the add-on will show the image associated with the first link I hover over. When I hover over different links to different images, it keeps showing the first image.
I am using this on a plant database, where I can hover over each plant and show an image of it. I still have not gotten it to properly show, but it's so close!